# Revolution Slider not loading after minification with fast velocity plugin wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have optimized my website with fast velocity minify plugin. Everything has done very fine, only problem arises is that slider revolution is not loading. Rest of the site is working properly. I have check the inspect element and the console error is: "undefined index:

```
 jQuery(function() {
    tpj = jQuery;
    if (tpj("#rev_slider_26_1").revolution == undefined)
    {
        revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_26_1");
    }
```

You can see that revolution == undefined is listed in code. Can someone please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Where/what is that code from? Honestly, if fast velocity breaks my revolution slider, I would not use fast velocity, or try a different minifying plugin.

Comment: I just did some research, I suspect most/all minify to break revolution slider, but you could try another one and see if it still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but I learned that fast velocity has a way to exclude scripts from the minification. You could try excluding the rev slider related scripts.